# Python: import body of email to text file result in PermissionError

Tags: python, python-3.x, imaplib

I saw this code from a post here and wanted to see how it works: [importing gmail text content to a text file with python returns nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22590945/importing-gmail-text-content-to-a-text-file-with-python-returns-nothing)

But when I try it an error appears. `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\email1.txt'`

this is the code:

```
import imaplib
import email
mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
mail.login('myemail', 'mypassword')
mail.list()
mail.select('inbox')

result, data = mail.uid('search', None, "ALL")
i = len(data[0].split())
for x in range(i):
    latest_email_uid = data[0].split()[x]
    result, email_data = mail.uid('fetch', latest_email_uid, '(RFC822)')
    raw_email = email_data[0][1]

    raw_email_string = raw_email.decode('utf-8')
    email_message = email.message_from_string(raw_email_string)
for part in email_message.walk():
    if part.get_content_type() == "text/plain":
        body = part.get_payload(decode=True)
        save_string = "C:\\email" + str(x) + ".txt"
        myfile = open(save_string, 'a')
        myfile.write(str(body))
        myfile.close()
    else:
        continue
```

I'm guessing it has something to do with access of the folder I created in the C: location however I don't know what to do.

Comment: You are literally being told that you do not have the permission to that file. Can you try creating a file manually in __C:__

Comment: I did create it before trying to run the code.  I just created a folder though. Should i create a text file as well?

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with your code. Maybe try writing the file to another folder, perhaps C:\\Users\\SOMEUSER\\email1.txt

Comment: still the same error

Comment: How are you invoking the script?